# JodaTime - Display time in its own timezone

Tags: java, android, datetime, timezone, jodatime

My app is using JodaTime to manage date parsing and formatting.

I have this timestamp: `2018-07-24T15:30:00-07:00`.
How can display it as 3:30pm, regardless of the user's whereabouts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following code will print "3:30pm":

```
DateTimeFormatter iso = ISODateTimeFormat.dateTimeParser().withOffsetParsed();
DateTime tsp = iso.parseDateTime("2018-07-24T15:30:00-07:00");

DateTimeFormatter out = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("h:mma").withLocale(Locale.ENGLISH);

System.out.println(tsp); // 2018-07-24T15:30:00.000-07:00
System.out.println(out.print(tsp).toLowerCase()); // 3:30pm
```

The main problem is just that the parser does not retain the parsed offset of -7:00 but shifts it to your system timezone unless you also call `withOffsetParsed()`.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I needed.